# List of list string c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, parameters

I'm creating some methods for using CarlosAG ExcelXMLWriter, I want to improve this method in particular

```
public void insertaRango(Worksheet sheet, List<object> values, int columnMerge = 0, string styleID = null, DataType dt = DataType.String)
{
    WorksheetRow row = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
    WorksheetCell cell;
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        cell = row.Cells.Add();
        cell.Data.Text = value.ToString();
        cell.MergeAcross = columnMerge;
        cell.StyleID = styleID;
        cell.Data.Type = dt;
    }
}
```

it generates a range of data with some options, the main problem is if I want to write this data

```
//Client    Money       Date
//------    -----       ----------
//Jhon Doe  1,034.88    2013-02-01
//Chris S.  4,882.12    2013-02-08
//
//TOTAL     XXXXXXXX
```

I can't do a `=SUM` function for column "Money" because the List only accepts one type of data, if I set it to `string` numbers won't be used like that, if I use `int` strings won't be able to parse... The same problem is present for rest of params for this method, it can't be one param for each item...

So basically what I want to do something like this, but I'm lost...

```
Objects {
    "Item 1" { // This is the value of the cell.
        dt => String,
        columnMerge => 0,
        styleID => "MyStyle",
    },
    "Item 2" { // This is the value of the cell.
        dt => String,
        columnMerge => 3,
        styleID => "MyStyle2",
    },
    "1,034.88" { // This is the value of the cell.
        dt => Number,
        columnMerge => 0,
        styleID => "numberStyle",
    }
}
```

And then, of course, parse everything on the method...

I hope I've explained everything good, thank you.
**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer given, I've added the constructor to the class and now everything is working, thank you.

```
public class CellValue
{
    public CellValue()
    {
        ColumnMerge = 0;
        StyleID = "Default";
        DataType = DataType.String;
        Value = null;
    }
    public int ColumnMerge { get; set; } // Combinación de celdas indice base 0.
    public string StyleID { get; set; } // Estilo deseado para la celda (consultar método generarEstilos).
    public DataType DataType { get; set; } // Tipo de datos de la celda ()
    public object Value { get; set; } // Valor de la celda.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to set individual parameters for each cell, declare container type for cell values:

```
class CellValue
{
    public int ColumnMerge { get; set; }
    public string StyleID { get; set; }
    public DataType DataType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

and pass list of `CellValue` instead of list of `object`:

```
    public void insertaRango(Worksheet sheet, List<CellValue> values)
    {
        WorksheetRow row = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
        WorksheetCell cell;
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            cell = row.Cells.Add();
            cell.Data.Text = value.Value.ToString();
            cell.MergeAcross = value.ColumnMerge;
            cell.StyleID = value.StyleID;
            cell.Data.Type = value.DataType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it working!! BTW, I had default values on the method, now I haven't theese default values... How can I set them back, so I only need to set them if needed for special cells?

Comment: You need to create a `CellValue` instance from each item of `{ "N. ORDEN", "NUMERO REFERENCIA", "IMPORTE", "SUC", "EMISORA" }`.

Comment: @user1381537: "now I haven't theese default values" - write a constructor for `CellValue`, which will set defaults for properties.